# The Complete Order button is disabled

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

In Acumatica, via import scenario, I have included the command <Action: Complete Order> (Complete).  The import breaks, and gives the error "The Complete Order button is disabled."

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to troubleshoot something like this is to perform the task manually. you will need to figure out what needs to be done first to enable the button and then get your import scenario to do the equivalent automatically.